# trigger power shell script on button click

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, custom-actions

we are having a requirement,when we click on a button in SharePoint page,we need to trigger workflow...

Can any one help on this how we can achieve this functionality

Answer (score 1):

What does the PowerShell script do? This seems like a very convulted way of approaching the problem; anything you can do in PowerShell you can do in a C# assembly called from the custom page.

Why don't you take a look at this tutorial? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231557.aspx

Then you can convert your powershell code to C# and execute it from an ASP button click.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could achieve this.

[Designer](http://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePointWorkflowButton.htm) way.

or [fiddling](http://sympmarc.com/2010/11/29/kicking-off-a-sharepoint-workflow-from-a-button-and-much-more-2/) with code.